# Copy the shared preferences XML file from /data on Samsung device failed

Tags: android

There's an exporting feature in my application. It's just a copy operation since all my settings are store in shared preference.

I just copy the xml file from /data/data/package.name/shared_prefs/settings.xml to SD card. It works fine on my HTC desire. However, it might not work on Samsung devices, and i got the following error while I try to copy the file.

```
I/System.out( 3166): /data/data/package.name/shared_prefs/settings.xml (No such file or directory) 
in the directory.
```

Anyone know how to fix it, or is there another simple way to store the shared preference ?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone know if this is still an issue on more recent devices? In particular API 23 (Marshmallow) and later

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CommonsWare's suggestion would a be clever hack, but unfortunately it won't work.

Samsung does not always put the shared_prefs directory in the same parent directory as the `getFilesDir()`.

I'd recommend testing for the existence of (hardcode it, except for package name):
`/dbdata/databases/<package_name>/shared_prefs/package.name_preferences.xml` and if it exists use it, otherwise fall back to either CommonsWare's suggestion of `new File(getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs")` or just `/data/data/<package_name>/shared_prefs/package.name_preferences.xml`.

A warning though that this method could potentially have problems if a user switched from a Samsung rom to a custom rom without wiping, as the `/dbdata/databases` file might be unused but still exist.

## More details

On some Samsung devices, such as the Galaxy S series running froyo, the setup is this:

### `/data/data/<package_name>/(lib|files|databases)`

Sometimes there's a shared_prefs there too, but it's just Samsung's attempt to confuse you! Don't trust it! (I think it can happen as a left over from a 2.1 upgrade to 2.2, but it might be a left over from users switching roms. I don't really know, I just have both included in my app's bug report interface and sometimes see both files).

And:

### `/dbdata/databases/<package_name>/shared_prefs`

That's the real shared_prefs directory.

However on the Galaxy Tab on Froyo, it's weird. Generally you have: `/data/data/<package_name>/(lib|shared_prefs|files|databases)`

With no `/dbdata/databases/<package_name>` directory, but it seems the system apps do have:
`/dbdata/databases/<package_name>/yourdatabase.db`

And added bonus is that `/dbdata/databases/<package_name>` is not removed when your app is uninstalled. Good luck using SharedPreferences if the user ever reinstalls your app!

Comment: Wow, great, I think it's just what I need. I'll try it. One more questions. So in a general way, I should look up for the following directories in order, please correct me if the order is wrong. 
1./data/data/package.name 
2./dbdata/databases/package.name 
3./dbdata/data/package.name

Comment: I'd first check for (a) /dbdata/databases/package.name, then (b) /data/data/package.name . /dbdata/data/ was a typo by me (edited post to fix). (b) first counts on Samsung cleaning up which they don't do. (a) first counts on users cleaning up when switching from a Samsung rom to a normal rom. I'm betting that going from a Samsung rom to a normal rom would require wipe anyway, but I don't know.

Comment: Much better answer than the rest.

Answer (score 9):

Never never never never never never never never never hardwire paths.

Unfortunately, there's no `getSharedPreferenceDir()` anywhere that I can think of. The best solution I can think of will be:

```
new File(getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs")
```

This way if a device manufacturer elects to change partition names, you are covered.

Try this and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, new File(getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs") does return me "/data/data/<packageName>/files/../shared_prefs" but how to get value like "/data/data/<packageName>/shared_prefs" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get valid path on all devices - run method `Context.getSharedPrefsFile` defined as:

```
/**
 * {@hide}
 * Return the full path to the shared prefs file for the given prefs group name.
 *
 * <p>Note: this is not generally useful for applications, since they should
 * not be directly accessing the file system.
 */
public abstract File getSharedPrefsFile(String name);
```

Because of it hidden need use reflection and use fallback on fail:

```
private File getSharedPrefsFile(String name) {
    Context context = ...;
    File file = null;
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            try {
                Method m = context.getClass().getMethod("getSharedPreferencesPath", new Class[] {String.class});
                file = (File)m.invoke(context, new Object[]{name});
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.w("App TAG", "Failed call getSharedPreferencesPath", e);
            }
        }

        if (file == null) {
            Method m = context.getClass().getMethod("getSharedPrefsFile", new Class[] {String.class});
            file = (File)m.invoke(context, new Object[]{name});
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.w("App TAG", "Failed call getSharedPrefsFile", e);

        file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs/" + name + ".xml");
    }
    return file;
}
```

On some Samsungs implements like this:

```
public File getSharedPrefsFile(String paramString) {
    return makeFilename(getPreferencesDir(), paramString + ".xml");
}

private File getPreferencesDir() {
    synchronized (this.mSync) {
        if (this.mPreferencesDir == null) {
            this.mPreferencesDir = new File("/dbdata/databases/" + getPackageName() + "/", "shared_prefs");
        }
        File localFile = this.mPreferencesDir;
        return localFile;
    }
}
```

On other Android like this:

```
public File getSharedPrefsFile(String name) {
    return makeFilename(getPreferencesDir(), name + ".xml");
}

private File getPreferencesDir() {
    synchronized (mSync) {
        if (mPreferencesDir == null) {
            mPreferencesDir = new File(getDataDirFile(), "shared_prefs");
        }
        return mPreferencesDir;
    }
}

private File getDataDirFile() {
    if (mPackageInfo != null) {
        return mPackageInfo.getDataDirFile();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Not supported in system context");
}
```

After while Google change API for level 24 and later:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6a6cdafaec56fcd793214678c7fcc52f0b860cfc%5E%21/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java

Comment: From API level 24, the javadoc for `getSharedPrefsFile` says `@deprecated` and to use the abstract `getSharedPreferencesPath(String name)` instead. Javadoc for `getSharedPreferencesPath` says `@removed` instead of `@hide`, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in Samsung P1010 with:

`//I'm in a IntentService class`

`File file = this.getDir("shared_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);`

I got:
"/data/data/package.name/app_shared_prefs"

It works fine to me. I can run ffmpeg in this folder.

Look:

[Context.getDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score -1):

You have to create the `shared_prefs` directory:

```
try{
    String dir="/data/data/package.name/shared_prefs";

    // Create one directory
    boolean success = (new File(dir)).mkdirs();
    if (success) {
      // now copy the file
    }

}catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Also... the package of your app is `package.name`? Make sure you are referring to the right package.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, would you mind to explain more about why i need to create the folder? In my application, I use shared preference to store the settings, thus the folder and the xml file should be all created automatically.

Comment: The real package name is com.xxx.xxx. It should be no problem. thanks.

Comment: BTW, I copy the file from /data/data/package.name/shared_prefs/settings.xml to sdcard.

Comment: If the folder already existed, then no, you don't have to create it. Then make sure the file settings.xml is there...