# Shared Preferences Path not exists on some phone?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

The default shared preferences path on Android is

```
/data/data/package_name/shared_prefs/package_name_preferences.xml
```

In my app, I have an option to backup this file to SD-card.
But on the phone Samsung Galaxy S, it seems there is no path or file like

```
/data/data/package_name/..
```

A user reported to me that he is getting an error on backup.

If I check the error, I can see:

```
/data/data/xxx.xxxx.xxxx/shared_prefs/xxx.xxxx.xxxx_preferences.xml (No such file or directory)
```

How can this happen?

Here is my code to create the path:

```
Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + "/data/xxx.xxxx.xxxx/shared_pref/xxx.xxxx.xxxxx_preferences.xml"
```

Comment: Question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531289/copy-the-shared-preferences-xml-file-from-data-on-samsung-device-failed . Check my answer there for Samsung paths.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered reimplementing it using Android Cloud Backup so the backup goes to the cloud instead of the SD card?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use absolute file paths like that in your app because not all Android installs use the same paths.

Try using: SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(xxx.xxxx.xxxx_preferences.xml, 0);

That will access your Shared preferences using relative addressing and not absolute addressing and should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but i need a absolute path. I do a backup of the SharedPreferences to the SD-Card. getSharedPreferences does not solve my problem because i don't get the path.

And the sharedPreference path is always in the same path on Android installs... So far as i know!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to get path of shared preferences below like this.This is work for me.

```
File f = getDatabasePath("MyPrefsFile.xml");

if (f != null)
    Log.i("TAG", f.getAbsolutePath());
```