# Save SharedPreferences files into custom dir or get default SharedPreferences dir

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to save SharedPreferences files into custom dir? Let's say into `/data/data/package.name/my_prefs/`.

Or is it possible to retrieve the directory SharedPreferences are saved by default to?

P.S. Hardcoding the path `/data/data/package.name/shared_prefs/` is not the solution.

Comment: You can try this : `File dir = getDir("shared_prefs");`

Comment: This will only create directory `/data/data/package.name/app_shared_prefs/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Or is it possible to retrieve the directory SharedPreferences are
>   saved by default to?

Yes.

This is basically the [dataDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#dataDir) /shared_prefs which you can get from the *ApplicationInfo* object (which in turn you can get from the *PackageManager*). (Also, it might be the same as the "getFilesDir" dir you can get easily from *Context* itself? Not sure, didn't check that.)

From the source, starting with *Context.getSharedPreferences* ([ContextImpl source](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java)):

```
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
        SharedPreferencesImpl sp;
        File prefsFile;
        boolean needInitialLoad = false;
        synchronized (sSharedPrefs) {
            sp = sSharedPrefs.get(name);
            if (sp != null && !sp.hasFileChangedUnexpectedly()) {
                return sp;
            }
            prefsFile = getSharedPrefsFile(name);
...

public File getSharedPrefsFile(String name) {
        return makeFilename(getPreferencesDir(), name + ".xml");
    }

private File getPreferencesDir() {
        synchronized (mSync) {
            if (mPreferencesDir == null) {
                mPreferencesDir = new File(getDataDirFile(), "shared_prefs");
            }
            return mPreferencesDir;
        }
    }

private File getDataDirFile() {
        if (mPackageInfo != null) {
            return mPackageInfo.getDataDirFile();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Not supported in system context");
    }
```

And "mPackageInfo" is an instance of *LoadedApk*:

```
public File getDataDirFile() {
        return mDataDirFile;
    }

mDataDirFile = mDataDir != null ? new File(mDataDir) : null;

 mDataDir = aInfo.dataDir;
```

And that brings us back to *ApplicationInfo*.

I'd say if you don't want to rely on the convention */data/data/<package_name>/shared_prefs* then it should be safe to get the "dataDir" and rely on "shared_prefs" from there?

Comment: On some firmwares `shared_prefs` can be saved in other places. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531289/copy-the-shared-preferences-xml-file-from-data-on-samsung-device-failed

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it possible to retrieve the directory SharedPreferences are
>   saved by default to?

See this answer to know how get path in safe way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33849650/1504248