# When is a shared preferences file first created?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I wanted to know when is a shared preference file created for the first time?

I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="User settings">  
        <EditTextPreference android:title="User Name"
        android:key="userName" android:summary="Please Enter User Name"></EditTextPreference>  
        <EditTextPreference android:title="Password"
        android:key="password" android:summary="Password Here"
        android:inputType="textPassword"></EditTextPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>  

</PreferenceScreen>  


  public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);  
    }  
}
```

Also, how can i use getSharedpreference(), with filename? I don't know if I have to first create this file and place it in app's data directory?

I meant When is a shared preferences file first created: when the application is installed, or some time later? If later, when?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `getSharedPreferences(name, mode)` method automatically creates the file with the name specified, so you don't need to create it. Actually, the exact location and name of this preference file is not documented, so I'd suggest you don't rely on some conventions when trying to [access this file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194883/save-sharedpreferences-files-into-custom-dir-or-get-default-sharedpreferences-di), since the location and name may be changed in future - `SharedPreferences` should be the only way to access this file.

The preference file with certain name is created when `getSharedPreferences(name, mode)` or [`addPreferencesFromResource(preferencesResId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#addPreferencesFromResource%28int%29) is called for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you are talking about here.

You don't need to create any files when dealing with PreferenceScreens or SharedPreferences. That is handled by SharedPreferences behind the scenes. I believe that happens when you first set a value in the Preference screen but I honestly am not sure.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String username = preferences.getString("username", "defaultvalue");
String password = preferences.getString("password", "defaultvalue");
```

That code would get the SharedPreferences for your PreferenceScreen once they have been set. If they haven't been set, you use the default values.

Comment: thanks for it.. i meant When is a shared preferences file first created: when the application is installed,
or some time later? If later, when?

Comment: I believe it is created either the first time that the PreferenceScreen appears, or when an item in the PreferenceScreen is first set by the user. As I said before, I am not totally sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other comments, you'll never be directly interacting with shared preferences files. You read and write values to them using a SharedPreferences object. The `Context.getSharedPreferences()` method takes in a string as its first argument (the name of the shared preferences file you want to interact with) and returns a `SharedPreferences` object. According to the [documentation for the `getSharedPreferences()` method:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int))

> If a preferences file by this name does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor (SharedPreferences.edit()) and then commit changes (Editor.commit()).

So *that's* when the shared preferences file is created. Other methods that return SharedPreferences objects are just doing the same thing in different contexts.

For example:

The [`Activity.getPreferences()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)) method

> simply calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

Answer (score 0):

The Shared Preferences would created under /data/data/appname/shared_prefs/prefs_name.xml

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we call the menthod **getSharedPreferences("file_name", mode)**
It is going to check if the xml file corresponding to the file name we provided already exists or not, if it exists already it will use the existing one for the operation we are performing otherwise it is going to create a new file with the name we provide

We can check this file in Android studio Device File Explorer->data/data/<package_name>/shared_prefs folder