# Android Preference file set name

Tags: android

I am currently following this tutorial [Android Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

my problem is it save the app settings as

```
com.packagename_preferences.xml
```

Is there any way I can set its file name? like this

```
mychoosennamehere_preferences.xml
```

or

somenamesiwanttouse.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can rename the preference file but you should not do that. Actually, the exact location and name of this preference file is not documented, so I'd suggest you don't rely on some conventions when trying to [access this file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194883/save-sharedpreferences-files-into-custom-dir-or-get-default-sharedpreferences-di), since the location and name may be changed in future - `SharedPreferences` should be the only way to access this file.And your App will stop working.

Anyhow here is the way to rename your preference file

```
String fileName="mychoosennamehere_preferences";
File f=new File("/data/data/eywa.musicplayer/shared_prefs/"+"com.packagename_preferences"+".xml");
 f.renameTo(new File("/data/data/eywa.musicplayer/shared_prefs/"+fileName+".xml"));

 SharedPreferences  mySharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(fileName,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
editor.remove(PlayListName);
editor.putString(fileName, fileName);
 editor.commit();
 PlayListName=fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the .xml file (right-click -> rename).

Then change the name in your code that points to the file.