# How to get path of Shared Preferences in Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Can any body explain that how to get absolute path of shared preferences.I read that shared preferences stored in different paths in some devices. Is it possible to get path dynamically.

Comment: This question has already discussed. You can see [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531289/copy-the-shared-preferences-xml-file-from-data-on-samsung-device-failed

Answer (score 0):

I dont think absolute path can be retrieved using Android SDK APIs.