# Save SharedPreferences file for backup purposes

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to save user progress in my game which is essentially all saved in a sharedprefrences file.

So, instead of using third party services, I am wondering if I can simply save the whole file on my server
and in time just pull it and apply it locally?

So the question is - can a sharedprefrences file be saved as a bulk?

Comment: It's just an xml file so, yes

Comment: Yes, xml but how to take it as a whole, not sure the Android system allow this. I can itereate it but can i take all of it?

Comment: For one user you want one single shared preference file and want to share periodically updates to that file?

Answer (score 0):

for saving progress locally you can use SQLite database or Room Database so you can easily update in the future if you want to update ... I will recommend room database rather than sqlite3 because that is consuming more time and room database easily you can work on crud operation without taking too much time ...and sharedpreference for getting issue if you want to update value and more time to take your job and confusion so use room database...easy and less time

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but a good recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, you can find SharedPreferences xml file in `/data/data/<your.package.name>/shared_prefs/` directory. But it depends on manufacter, so it's not guaranteed.
(For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531289/copy-the-shared-preferences-xml-file-from-data-on-samsung-device-failed)).

For getting shared pref file Context has folowing methods - new `File getSharedPreferencesPath(String name);` and depercated `File getSharedPrefsFile(String name);`
(According to [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/android10-c2f2-release/core/java/android/content/Context.java) )

You can use one of them(or both for different Android versions) via reflection.

But, actually, it's not reccomended approach. Better choice is write your own prefs synchronization by copying all values with all keys.
Or just store preferences in your own database.